# Optimisation problem with two pandas dataframes using GEKKO

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I have two dataframes with the same format looking like the following:

df1

```
            Value_0  Value_1  Value_2 ...
Date                                        
2020-11-07  7.830    19.630   30.584  ...
2020-11-08  11.100   34.693   40.589  ...
2020-11-09  12.455   34.693   41.236  ...
.
.
.
```

df2

```
            Value_0  Value_1  Value_2 ...
Date                                        
2020-11-07  153.601  61.014   55.367  ...
2020-11-08  119.011  70.560   49.052  ...
2020-11-09  133.925  103.417  61.651  ...
.
.
.
```

I'm trying to:

1. Make a linear interpolation between each consecutive matching points (so y1 = df1.Value_0, y2 = df1.Value_1, x1 = df2.Value_0, x2 = df2.Value_1).
2. Maximize the product of df1 and df2 for each Date and column pair considering all posible values from the interpolation.

My current approach is the following (This goes inside a loop to evaluate each pair of columns and then store the optimisation only for the highest value, but I'm neglecting it here for sake of simplicity):

```
i = 0 # Example for only one use case

# Initial model
m = gekko()

# Variables         
y1 = np.array(df1['Value_'+str(i)])
y2 = np.array(df1['Value_'+str(i+1)])
x1 = np.array(df2['Value_'+str(i)])
x2 = np.array(df2['Value_'+str(i+1)])

s = [None]*len(y1)
c = [None]*len(y1)
ex = [None]*len(y1)

for j in range(len(y1)):
    s[j] = (y1[j]-y2[j])/(x1[j]-x2[j]) # slope
    c[j] = (x1[j]*y2[j] - x2[j]*y1[j])/(x1[j]-x2[j]) # y intersect
    ex[j] = -c[j]/s[j] # x intersect
    
p = m.Var(lb=0, ub=y2) # specific boundaries for case when i=0
n = m.Var(lb=x2, ub=ex) # specific boundaries for case when i=0

# Constraint
m.Equation((s[j]*n)+c[j]==p for j in range(len(y1))) # equation of a line

# Objective function
m.Maximize(n*p)

m.solve(disp=False)

#print('p:'+str(p.value))
#print('n:'+str(n.value))
```

It's my first time using Gekko and I'm getting "@error: Inequality Definition
invalid inequalities: z > x < y". I would appreciate any clues regarding what's wrong with the code/variables definition.

Answer (score 0):

The lower and upper bound needs to be a single value, unless you define a separate variable for each data row. Is this a suitable replacement?

```py
p = m.Var(lb=0, ub=max(y2))
n = m.Var(lb=min(x2), ub=max(ex))
```

Try using `IMODE=2` to define the equation once and apply it to each data row. Here is a modification of the script that runs in mode 2.

```py
from gekko import gekko
import numpy as np

# Initial model
m = gekko()

# Variables
ns = 10
y1 = np.random.rand(ns)
y2 = np.random.rand(ns)+1
x1 = np.random.rand(ns)
x2 = np.random.rand(ns)+1

s = [None]*len(y1)
c = [None]*len(y1)
ex = [None]*len(y1)

for j in range(len(y1)):
    # slope
    s[j] = (y1[j]-y2[j])/(x1[j]-x2[j])
    # y-intercept
    c[j] = (x1[j]*y2[j] - x2[j]*y1[j])/(x1[j]-x2[j])
    # x-intercept
    ex[j] = -c[j]/s[j]

s = m.Param(s); c = m.Param(c)
p = m.Var(lb=0, ub=max(y2))
n = m.Var(lb=min(x2), ub=max(ex))

# Constraint
m.Equation(s*n+c==p)

m.options.IMODE=2

# Objective function
m.Maximize(n*p)

m.solve(disp=True)
```

If separate upper and lower bounds are needed for each interpolation, then create an array of variables such as:

```py
p = m.Array(m.Var,ns,lb=0)
n = m.Array(m.Var,ns)
```

[More information on the modes of calculation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/imode.html) are shown in the documentation.

**Unique Inequality Constraints for Each Data Row**

If unique inequality constraints are required for each data row, use inequality constraints as an equation definition.

```py
p = m.Var(lb=0)
n = m.Var()

# implement constraints
x2 = m.Param(x2)
y2 = m.Param(y2)
ex = m.Param(ex)

m.Equation(p<y2)
m.Equations([n>x2,n<ex])
```

Below is a full script with the inequality constraints. The problem may be infeasible if all of the inequality constraints cannot be simultaneously satisfied.

```py
from gekko import gekko
import numpy as np

# Initial model
m = gekko()

# Variables
ns = 10
y1 = np.random.rand(ns)
y2 = np.random.rand(ns)+1
x1 = np.random.rand(ns)
x2 = np.random.rand(ns)+1

s = [None]*len(y1)
c = [None]*len(y1)
ex = [None]*len(y1)

for j in range(len(y1)):
    # slope
    s[j] = (y1[j]-y2[j])/(x1[j]-x2[j])
    # y-intercept
    c[j] = (x1[j]*y2[j] - x2[j]*y1[j])/(x1[j]-x2[j])
    # x-intercept
    ex[j] = -c[j]/s[j]

s = m.Param(s); c = m.Param(c)
p = m.Var(lb=0)
n = m.Var()

# implement constraints
x2 = m.Param(x2)
y2 = m.Param(y2)
ex = m.Param(ex)

m.Equation(p<y2)
m.Equations([n>x2,n<ex])

# Constraint
m.Equation(s*n+c==p)

m.options.IMODE=2

# Objective function
m.Maximize(n*p)

m.solve(disp=True)
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your help. In my case, separate upper and lower bounds are needed for each iteration, so I created two arrays for p and n inside the for loop. However when implementing the code, I'm getting: error: Equation Definition
 Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)
 (((p1)*([[0]
 STOPPING...     Any clues, what might be the issue?

Comment: Sure, I'll add an additional comment to my answer.